# MySQL locate first and last event per day

Tags: mysql

I have a string of events being logged on a 5 minute basis throughout the day in a MySQL DB. I need to identify the first event (where logid > 0) of the day as well as the last (where logid=0), but struggling to find a simple SQL solution.

A 0 will be stored in the logid field in every row starting at midnight until the first event is triggered, at which point it will change to a number > 0. Then various events will be triggered logging a number > 0 for the remainder of the day, at which point the field will once again be logged as 0 until midnight, when the process starts over again.

Is there a quick and simple way to pull the rows identifying the time when the events start, and another result showing when the events end?

```
CREATE TABLE logs( 
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  date DATETIME, 
  logid INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

This is the test data:

```
id  date                logid
1   2018-11-12 01:05:00 0   
2   2018-11-12 01:10:00 0   
3   2018-11-12 01:15:00 0
4   2018-11-12 01:20:00 0   
5   2018-11-12 01:05:00 0   
…
84  2018-11-12 06:35:00 0   
85  2018-11-12 06:35:00 1   
86  2018-11-12 06:40:00 1   
87  2018-11-12 06:45:00 1   
88  2018-11-12 06:50:00 1   
…
164 2018-11-12 15:20:00 1   
165 2018-11-12 15:25:00 0   
166 2018-11-12 15:30:00 0   
167 2018-11-12 15:35:00 0
```

Desired Result set:

```
85  2018-11-12 06:35:00 1   
165 2018-11-12 15:25:00 0
```

I'm not concerned about logid up until the first instance where it is greater than 0. But I need to identify the first instance where logid > 0, and then the next chronological instance where logid = 0 again.

My primary attempt was to group and order on the date and logid (edit: failed attempt removed for clarity)

Here's my latest attempt

```
       (SELECT *
        FROM logs
        WHERE logid>0
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date
        limit 1
    )UNION ALL(   
        SELECT *
        FROM logs
        WHERE logid>0
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date DESC
        limit 1)
```

Getting closer, but not quite there. This gives me the correct first row where logid = 1, but it gives me the last row where logid = 1 (id 164) rather than the following row where logid = 0 (id=165).

Is it possible to select the penultimate row of a set if I change limit 1 to 2?
Any other pointers to keep me moving forward?

Comment: You should really show us some table data which explains the problem.

Comment: Please put some efforts in framing a question with  relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: You'll get better responses if you structure your sql and data so it's easier to read.  It's an arcane jumble.

Comment: Please add the corresponding expected output to the given sample data

Comment: 'The applicable field' - if you mean logid why not say so?

Comment: In hindsight, of course I should have. The 'applicable field' will be one of several possible fields depending on the table and or user. I figured a generic description would be acceptable. My apologies.

Comment: Can you explain why `2018-11-12 01:05:00 0 ` is not your first result?  Also, can you please include an example of something you've tried?

Comment: 2018-11-12 01:05:00 0 is not my first result because I'm only interested in the first result where the logid switches to 1, and then when it switches back to 0. Any data before the logid switches to 1 is counted as part of the logging from the prior day.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't seem to be a problem for others, but I thought I would post the answer I came up with in case anyone runs into a similar situation in the future.

```
SET @v1 := (SELECT date 
        FROM logs
        WHERE logid > 0
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date
        limit 1);

(SELECT *
        FROM logs
        WHERE date>@v1 and logid>0
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date
        limit 1
) UNION ALL (
SELECT *
        FROM logs
        WHERE date>@v1 and logid=0
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date
        limit 1
)
```